# servidor não retorna dados que eu envio com angular2

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-services

o código do component

```
 onSubmit(form){ 
    var success = false;
    var error = false;

    this.http.post(`http://localhost/api/`, 
    JSON.stringify(form.value))
    .map(res => res)
    .subscribe(dados => console.log(dados));

  }
```

o código php do servidor

```
if(!isset($_POST)):
    ResultJson(['erro'=> true, 'messagem'=> 'nenhum dado foi informado']);
else:
    var_dump($_POSt);
endif;
```

o problema é que retorna um array vazio já tentei de varias formas e não consigo resolver alguém consegue me ajudar? agradeço pela força de vcs

Comment: Veja que tem um erro de digitação no seu código PHP: `var_dump($_POSt);` -> `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: consegui resolver rsrs o problema não era esse mas consegui obrigado

Comment: Se já conseguiu é viavel apagar a pergunta ou responder ela você mesmo e marcar sua resposta como correta